# confused by commas

Tags: grammar

The GET method should be safe, that is, without any side effects for which users are held responsible.

I got confused by the commas. Does it mean "The GET method should be safe. In other words, it doesn't have any side effects that users are held responsible for."

Answer (score 1):

A brief answer:
Your parse is probably correct.  The first comma is too weak -- it should be either a semicolon or period.

Comment: But the last comma shouldn’t exist, “that is without any side effects for which users are held responsible” is fine. So is the writer’s mistake?

Comment: Removing the second comma changes the parse, making "that is ..." into an independent statement instead of an explanation of why the method should be safe.